Golub-Reinsch SVD
I am trying to implement the Golub-Reinsch & Glolub Kahan SVD algorithm in python and the algorithm 1b & 1c(page 6).I am also using Matrix Computation (Gene Golub, vanLoan, 4th Ed) as a reference. The first part of the algorithm (Algorithm 1a) do the Bidiagonalization of Matrix A. In my case,
$A = \begin{bmatrix} 
5  & -1 & -1 & 6  & 4  & 0  \\
-3 &  1 &  4 & -7 & -2 & -3 \\
1  &  3 & -4 & 5  & 4  & 7  \\
0  &  4 & -1 & 1  & 4  & 5  \\
4  &  2 &  3 & 1  & 6  & -1 \\
3  & -3 & -5 & 8  & 0  & 2  \\
0  & -1 & -4 & 4  & -1 & 3  \\
-5 &  4 & -3 & -2 & -1 & 7  \\
3  &  4 & -3 & 6  & 7  & 7
\end{bmatrix}$
import numpy as np
np.set_printoptions(suppress=True, precision=5)

epsilon = 1e-10

def HouseholderVector(x):
    n = x.size
    sigma = x[1:n].dot(x[1:n])
    v = x.copy()
    v[0] = 1
    
    if n > 1:
        if sigma <= np.finfo(np.float64).eps and x[0] >= 0:
            beta = 0
        elif sigma <= np.finfo(np.float64).eps and x[0] < 0:
            beta = -2
        else:
            mu = np.sqrt(x[0]*x[0] + sigma)
            if x[0] <= 0:
                v[0] = x[0] - mu
            else:
                v[0] = -sigma / (x[0] + mu)
        beta = 2*v[0]*v[0]/(sigma+v[0]*v[0])
        v = v / v[0]
    else:
        beta = 0
        v = 0
    return beta, v
    
def Bidiagonalization(A):
    m, n = A.shape
    U = np.eye(m, m)
    V = np.eye(n, n)
    B = A.copy()
    for j in range(0, n): 
        beta, v = HouseholderVector(B[j:m,j])
        H1 = np.eye(m)
        H1[j:m, j:m] = np.eye(m-j) - beta*np.outer(v, v)
        B[j:m, j:m] = np.matmul(H1[j:m, j:m], B[j:m, j:n])
        B[j+1:m, j] = 0.0
        U = np.matmul(U, H1)
        if j <= n - 3:
            beta, v = HouseholderVector(B.T[j+1:n,j])
            H2 = np.eye(n)
            H2[j+1:n, j+1:n] = np.eye(n-j-1) - beta*np.outer(v, v)
            B.T[j+1:n, j:m] = np.matmul(H2[j+1:n, j+1:n], B.T[j+1:n, j:m])
            B[j, j+2:n] = 0.0
            V = np.matmul(V, H2)
    return U, B, V

$$B = \begin{bmatrix} 
9.69536 & 14.3956 &0 &0 &0 &0\\
0& 10.9951 &16.3847 &0 &0 &0\\
0& 0& 2.44363 &11.7661& 0& 0\\
0& 0& 0& -3.6864\times 10^{-15} &-9.86671\times 10^{-17}& 0\\
0& 0& 0& 0& -4.14279\times 10^{-16}& 6.51552\times 10^{-16}\\
0& 0& 0& 0& 0& -9.85448\times 10^{-16}\\
0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0\\
0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0\\
0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0
\end{bmatrix}$$
converted to $B = \begin{bmatrix} 
9.69536 & 14.3956 &0 &0 &0 &0\\
0& 10.9951 &16.3847 &0 &0 &0\\
0& 0& 2.44363 &11.7661& 0& 0\\
0& 0& 0& -3.6864\times 10^{-15} &-9.86671\times 10^{-17}& 0\\
0& 0& 0& 0& -4.14279\times 10^{-16}& 6.51552\times 10^{-16}\\
0& 0& 0& 0& 0& -9.85448\times 10^{-16}
\end{bmatrix}$
Implementing $\textbf{Algorithm 1b: Step 2:}$

Blocking B in the p, n-p-q, q size. This part is a bit confusing. $B_{2,2}$ has non-zero super diagonal and $B_{3,3}$ diagonal (size of q is straightforward) . What about $B_{1,1}$? How to decide for p? Also what is the use of $B_{1,1}$? In Algorithm 1c, we only use $B_{2,2}$ part.

Some of the diagonal and super diagonal elements of $B$ are close to machine epsilon. Can they be assumed zero?


There is not enough material online on the details of the algorithm. Hopefully, when I completely write the code, which sample matrix I should test to know it can give accurate result for all?
*** This code is not efficient and just a trial version. All the effort is to understand the algorithm properly.
